# Form events are not fired through NavigationService

Tags: wpf, windowsformshost, navigationservice

I have WindowsFormsHost inside the WPF page say Page1

WindowsFormsHost has child winform say Form1.

Form1 has Paint method Form1_Paint();

I am navigating from Page1 to Page2 using NavigationService.

When I came back from Page2 to Page1 using NavigationService.GoBack() Page_Loaded event of Page1 fires but Form1_Paint() method doesn't fire.

I want the  WinForm event which fires when Page_Loaded() event got fired through Back Navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created new event which will get raised through Back Navigation.